# "Undefined reference to 'bootmain'" error during xv6 installation through cygwin

Tags: operating-system, cygwin, xv6

I am trying to get xv6 running on my windows laptop through cygwin and it shows this error: `undefined reference to bootmain.`

Help please. (screen text given below)

```
gcc -fno-pic -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie -fno-pic -O -nostdinc -I. -c bootmain.c
gcc -fno-pic -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie -fno-pic -nostdinc -I. -c bootasm.S
ld -m    elf_i386 -N -e start -Ttext 0x7C00 -o bootblock.o bootasm.o bootmain.o
ld: bootasm.o:/home/kaulv/xv6-public/bootasm.S:66: undefined reference to `bootmain'
make: *** [Makefile:106: bootblock] Error 1
```

Comment: How do you launch the build?
I'm not sure that it's easy to build `xv6` with cygwin

Comment: Isn't it possible using qemu?